# Using XBMC - Video not working

Tags: video

I'm not the most technical person in the world, so sorry if I am asking a stupid question :)

Basically, I am using a Raspberry Pi with XBMC to play music and video in my car. The sound is through the car's sound system and the video is playing through a touchscreen which was installed by the previous owner.

I've gotten the music aspect of things working, with no issues, but I am not having any success getting movies to play.

The touchscreen has a HDMI connection, and is working fine as a display, but when I play a movie file, there is sound, but no picture. I've gone through the settings to the best of my (limited) ability, but I cant see anything that I can change to get this to work for me.

Any ideas as to where I can start with this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

my first instinct on this would be that you do not have the correct video codecs for the movies you have. Hence XBMC understands what to do with the audio part, but not the video part.

you may want to find out the codec of your video files by running something like VLC media player.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/45927/how-to-find-out-what-codec-is-being-used-in-a-video

Comment: The default codecs can play mpeg4 but not mpeg2